# Excel Min(if()) Comparison of String Returns zero

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find the lowest price of a catalogued item set, as long as the item is unsold. I've tried

```
=MIN(IF(E:E = "No",D:D))
```

but it always returns zero, even with MAX instead of MIN. I don't have a version of excel that works with `MINIFS`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using is an array formula. You need to enter it by pressing ctrl+shift+enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((D:D)*(E:E="No")),1)
```

I won't recommend using the whole columns in the formula though. use specified ranges like `E1:E200`